# Adding 10 rows between each row in my original table in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, for-loop, large-data, vba

I have a table with data where I want to insert exactly 20 rows between each row of my original table. I have tried running nested for loops to add each row per loop and to hop onto the next "original" row on my table to add another 20 rows below it. However, this takes forever since I have over 2000 rows on my spreadsheet. Is there any other way to do this? Any vba code I could use for this?

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Could you post the code you have been using until now?

Comment: `Screenupdating=false` at the beginning of your loop will speed this type of process up significantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub AddRows()
    ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Dim AddRows As Integer: AddRows = 10

    Dim i As Integer: i = lastrow

    Do While i <> 1
        Rows(i & ":" & i + AddRows - 1).Insert
        i = i - 1
    Loop

    ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: if you reverse the loop, then a counter is not needed

Comment: Great Point!  I'll update the answer.

Comment: Or you could do it without a loop using SpecialCells

Answer (score 0):

basis of a solution (ie change upper and lower bounds of loop and or add them programatically)

```
For i = 10 To 1 Step -1
    Rows(i + 1 & ":" & i + 10).Insert
Next
```

Comment: should be "i+20" and i need to look at how formatting (or mark up) works on this site before i come back!!